# Adding a video from YouTube using HTML

Tags: html, css, video, iframe, youtube

I am trying to add a video from YouTube to my webpage but I obviously miss some details. How could I add it?

```
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocSOXI350FE" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a video from YouTube on a webpage, simply tap the "share" button under that video, then press "Embed". You will see the lines of code. Copy everything. Now you should be able to see the video on your webpage.